# Making mysql result list links

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have been working on a library software that can search through a database of books and bring up a relevant one based off of a search term. When the results come up I want it to have a link or button for each result, so that when you click it, it will take you to another template page and fill the template page with information about that specific book. It would be preferable if it could be possible in either php or html.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do we link the mysql results.

Comment: Please show the code where you get result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo "ISBN : " . $row["isbn"]."<br>".
      "Author : " . $row["author"]. "<br>". 
      "Book Title : " . $row["name"]. "<br>" .
      "Status : ". $row["status"]. "<br>". "<br>";
```

if you are getting the result like this. Then just add `<a>` tag in your result.
For Example you want to add link on Book Title.

```
Book Title: <a href="add_the_page_name_which_you_want_to_link.extension"><?php echo $row['name']?></a>
```

In this Way you can add link to mysql result.